# $\sqrt{10}$ is an irreducible element in the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{10}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, integral-domain

How can we prove that $\sqrt{10}$ is an irreducible element in the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{10}$?


 I think in general this is true for $\sqrt{m}$ where $m$ is not a perfect square in the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{m}$ . Irreducibly is easy when we have $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}i\sqrt{m}$ since there we use the modulus technique but I'm stuck here.
**What I tried:** $\sqrt{10}=(a+b\sqrt{10})(c+d\sqrt{10})$ from here I concluded that $ad+bc=1$ and $ac+10bd=0$. I have tried this method further but I didn't get anywhere. Is this the right way or there are better techniques?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the *norm* map
$$
N:\Bbb Z[\sqrt{10}]\longrightarrow\Bbb Z,\qquad N(a+b\sqrt{10})=(a+b\sqrt{10})(a-b\sqrt{10})=a^2-10b^2.
$$
The reason why this map is important is because it is multiplicative, namely
$$
N(xy)=N(x)N(y)
$$
for all $x$, $y$. Now if an element decomposes as $z=xy$, the above gives a condition on norms. Now $N(\sqrt{10})=10$, so for any decomposition
$\sqrt{10}=xy$ we would have
$$
N(x)=\pm 2\qquad N(y)=\pm5
$$
At this point you should convince yourself that there are no elements of norm $\pm5$.

---

[Two answers where posted while I was writing this]

Comment: I didn't know anything about field norms. Thanks! I accept this answer since it's more detailed.

Comment: You still need to argue that $N(x)=\pm1$ iff $x$ is a unit because you might have $10=1 \cdot 10$ or $(-1)\cdot(-10)$.

Comment: @ihf: actually you need only the "only if" part, and it is rather obvious (if $z\bar z=\pm1$ then $\pm\bar z=z^{-1}$)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Use (or prove) that the norm $N(a+b\sqrt{10})=a^2-10b^2\in\mathbb Z$ is multiplicative: $N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$. Then argue that $10=N(\sqrt{10})$ cannot be written as a product of norms.

Comment: 5 seconds. ARGH.

Comment: Yeah. So I could stop typing ...